# the web page does not apear properly when i call the css file from javascript file

Tags: javascript, css, load, runtime

the project is in jsf and little bit slow to load and there is a lot
of other javascript files too. it apears to work fine when i add the css file
with a html tag

this is the javascript code

```
function linkcss()
 {
var $ = document; // shortcut
var cssId = 'myCss';  // you could encode the css path itself to generate id..
if (!$.getElementById(cssId))
    {
    var head  = $.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var link  = $.createElement('link');
    link.id   = cssId;
    link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
    link.type = 'text/css';
    link.href = 'css/home/csshome.css';
    link.media = 'all';
    head.appendChild(link);
    }
}
```

I call this function from `<body onload='linkcss()'>`

the problem is the page doesnt load properly the tables appear to be
stretched how can i gat around this.

Comment: What means "the page doesn't load properly"? Isn't the css document loaded at all or is something missing?

Comment: Its probably because, when the body onload() function is called, the page is already rendered by the browser and so the styles are not applied to the elements after the rendering.